# How can I determine how widespread support of OpenGL ES 3 is?

Tags: opengl-es

I am developing new app in OpenGL which should run on iOS and Android devices.
I'd like to use OpenGL ES 3. For iOS that's not a problem, since any iPhone newer than the 5 has GLES 3.

But I am not sure how wide-spread GLES 3 is in the Android world or if all new devices support it. How can I determine how much support exists for GLES 3 so I can determine if I should use it or fall back to an older version?

Comment: Since questions about which technology you should pick are not on topic here, I have edited your question to ask specifically about determining market penetration of GLES 3 (since that also fits with the existing answer).

Comment: For possible future readers, I have found one another page. There is no percentual statistics, based on current usage, but list of devices and their GL version with possible extensions is here: http://www.gpuinfo.org/ Or if we take a similarity betwen ES and WebGL, we can use: https://webglstats.com/

Comment: For Android, you can have a look at https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/#OpenGL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of how many devices support different APIs is usually easy to figure out by looking at public hardware stats of popular engines, such as unity and unreal. I recommend using multiple sources of stats to get better view of actual share of different device capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this wiki check](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL)...

> In June 2018, Apple deprecated OpenGL APIs on all of their platforms (iOS, macOS and tvOS), strongly encouraging developers to use their proprietary Metal API, which was introduced in 2014.

Comment: Just another nail in the coffin for Apple and the proliferation of "F*** Apple." You want to do anything with an Apple device using cross-platform standards? Tough. Use Apple-only technology. This is why I refuse to develop games and engines with Apple support.

Comment: @Casey I'm ready to bet that most games released nowadays are done using a third party game engine which abstracts most of this for the developer.

Comment: @Casey I totally agree. not hating on Apple but they need to be less stingy and understand that the world is really diverse and it wouldn't hurt leaving developers with other options that they are more accustomed to instead of having to conform to their ideals.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Yeah well some people don't like to be lazy stuck with propertiery engines that pull the plug whenever they like. What you added was basically nothing to the conversation.